# Excel: How to open the Data Entry form from VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, data-entry

There is a built-in data entry form in Excel. I have added a shortcut to this and its quite good. It has a few little issues (i.e. it depends what cell you have selected as to what data it fills in the form).

So I want to wrap it up into a macro and add my own button. My little macro will select the appropriate cell. So the question is, using VBA, how do you call the build-in Data Entry form?

**-EDIT-**

Seems my question is not clear... so here is some more:

There is a built-in data entry form that you can use, see here: [Built-in Data Entry Form](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/090717_data_form.htm)

I want to open this form using excel VBA, like this:

```
Sub OpenTheBuiltinDataEntryForm()
    ' Add code here to open the built-in data entry form...    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you are looking for is:

```
Activesheet.ShowDataForm
```

but note that your data table must begin within A1:B2 or be named Database or you will get an error.

Comment: Awesome!, I could not find that info anywhere, thanks :)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with the data table beginning somewhere else? or how do you name it database?

Comment: Select the whole data range and type Database in the name box on the left of the formula bar, or use the Name Manager on the Formulas tab.